# Rackmount Hardware Question

Tags: hardware, rack

This is just a quick question. I havent been able to find any recommendations from Google searching.

What is the maximum recommended weight for front mounting rack hardware?

**EDIT:**

I have a Hammond 1459 wallmount rack. It is only punched at the front for mounting (I don't know why they didn't punch the back). The depth of the rack is 16.4". I am looking to mount a 2U NAS/Server in the rack (weight is 20 lbs).

Is it sufficient to mount this front only?

If not, I have some follow-up questions:

1. What is the best way to punch proper EIA holes in the rear of the rack?
2. Where can I find such short depth rail kits? (I've looked quite a bit)

Answer (score 5):

Curiously enough it depends on the rack itself, there's no hard-and-fast limit as they vary wildly - check with your manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Anything heavier than a 1U switch is risky.

Servers are a definite no-no.  The vibration will kill them, and the weight will bend the ears and rack struts.

I think if i wanted to mount a 2-3U router or switch, I'd put the thing on a shelf.

Comment: I disagree.  For example, Cisco network equipment around here is typically mounted on two-post telco racks.  The difference is that the switches are attached along the entire vertical length of the device, not just with a small pair of rack ears.  Also, the racks are typically bolted into the floor.

Comment: Fair enough....